# How do I add a variable to the end of an object's key?

Tags: jquery, ajax, object, dynamic, key

I'm trying to pass this array filled with objects:

```
var steps = [
    {
        bla: blu,
        bla: blu,
        bla: blu
    },
    {
        // etc.. 3 more times same format
    }
];
```

to my codeigniter controller using jQuery's $.ajax() function.

I tried it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'index.php/worldmap/ajax/start_travelling',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        steps: steps
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

but I got a typeError and found out that the data object passed to the controller must be in the key => value format. I read that it does take a single object.

So i figured that if I passed the number of steps and each individuel step I'll put them together in an array again in my codeigniter controller.

So I ended up with:

```
var dataToSend = {
    num_steps: steps.length
};

var i = 1;

$.each( steps, function( index, value ) ){
    dataToSend.step+i = value; // I want the key to be step_1, step_2 etc..
    i += 1;
};

$.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'index.php/worldmap/ajax/start_travelling',
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataToSend,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

but as you can probably guess the **.step + 1** does not seem to work. What is the right syntax to do what I'm trying to do? Or if anyone knows a better way of passing a multi-level array to my ci controller please share :D

Comment: *`x + y = z` will never work in JavaScript.* The left-hand side of an `=` must be "assignable to" (it must be evaluatable as a Reference Specification Type). This means it must be a *variable* or *property*, but not an arbitrary expression. Now, remember that both `data.x` and `data["x"]` (hint: "x" can be any string in the latter case) represent a property (when data names an object) and Arrays can be simply indexed `data[idx]` (which is still just a property).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I used dataToSend["step_"+i] = value and it's working. Thanks again ^^

Comment: Glad it works :D If at all possible, I would use an array so that it can be written as `dataToSend[i]` (instead of having properties step_0, step_1, step_x..). Generally Arrays should be used for repeating sequences while (normal) Object/Properties should be used for a fixed set of named values.

Comment: That was what I first tried. But since I'm passing the array to a $.ajax --> method:'post' function, the array it holds can only have 1 dimension. And the result of what you just suggested is a multidimensional array since I would store the steps in the array I'm sending which would be way better but returns an error when posting it to my codeigniter controller. This is just an ugly workaround counting the steps and using a for loop instead, but it works :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON object is correctly formed, you should be able to read the data from PHP, you could provide more info showing the php code.

The only thing you could be missing is to stringify the data:

```
var steps = [
    {
        bla: blu,
        bla: blu,
        bla: blu
    },
    {
        // etc.. 3 more times same format
    }
];

var dataToSend = { steps: steps };

$.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'index.php/worldmap/ajax/start_travelling',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing, thanks a lot! Sorry for the late reply.